# How to create MSI installer using Inno Setup?

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup

I need to create an MSI installer. Currently I am creating an exe with Inno Setup. But I need MSI installer. Is it doable with Inno Setup? Or recommend something else if not?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inno Setup does not support creating MSI installers.

See also [Is it feasible/sensible to wrap an Inno Setup installer inside an MSI for easier distribution via AD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71203/850848)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It provided me clarity:)