# How to check if Windows supports x86 executables in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I have written an installation script for my backup program. I want to check in the script if the OS supports x86 executables. How to do that?

Please consider:

- pure x64 CPUs without x86 support
- ARM CPUs

Maybe currently there are no pure x64 CPUs and ARM Windows has an emulation mode for x86 (I am not sure).

But I want to be fit for the future.

On Android there is a function to get a list of supported architectures. I am looking for an equivalent in PowerShell.

Comment: I recommend to widen your search to [`.net`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) as the question isn't really PowerShell dependable. Once you know how to do this in `.net` (or even C#), you should be able to include it in PowerShell.

Comment: I'm curious why are you using PowerShell to install the program. Most Windows users would much prefer an MSI or APPX both of which will handle this kind of thing for you.

Comment: @MartinBrown My installation script has ~100 lines. As you see there is minimal effort. Also I don't have to pay any fees. But if there is a better option I am willing to switch.

Comment: [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is free and widely used. You don't need to write code for basic things like installing files but you also have the ability to write custom functions in Pascal script.

Comment: WiX Toolset (not the people that create web sites look here instead https://wixtoolset.org/) will create an MSI for free that you can distribute for free. As in not costing any money. While your 100 line script may be minimal effort, I'd bet it doesn't cover everything it should do. For example can it be uninstalled from the Applications section of the Settings app? Will it support easy installation from System Centre? It depends upon what you are doing exactly, but in the real world these things will often be more important than supporting OS architectures that don't yet exist.

Comment: @zett42 Thank you for this recommendation. I think I prefer InnoSetup over wixtoolset as I think MSI features are limited.

Comment: I've not used InnoSetup but it sound's like it would be a good choice as long as you don't go near big corporates. If you do you may end up like this chap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71203/is-it-feasible-sensible-to-wrap-an-inno-setup-installer-inside-an-msi-for-easier

Comment: @MartinBrown I have a small computer business and will install this on private computers. I don't need this active directory stuff which MSI provides. InnoSetup seams perfect as it is even free for commercial use. Also it's still in development (alive).

Answer (score 0):

Create an invisible x86 application and let it return a special value. At installation time, run it and check its return value.

> pure x64 CPUs without x86 support

As you already figured out for ARM CPUs, running x86 executables is unrelated to the features of the CPU. There is no correlation between an x64 CPU and running x86 code.

As for Powershell, Powershell is .NET and .NET can be compiled as AnyCPU. So maybe you don't even need to care that much?

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the actual architecture of the machine by looking at $Env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE if that says it is x86 you know you are on an x86 machine. This however does not tell you when you are not on an x86 machine if x86 is emulated.

To find out if an architecture is emulated, it is possible to call the [IsWow64GuestMachineSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64guestmachinesupported) API with all the [architecture constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/image-file-machine-constants) that you want to test for. There is no way to get a list of supported architectures. [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220209-00/?p=106239) (usually a reliable source) suggests this is because you would not know what to do with unknown results. Calling IsWow64GuestMachineSupported can be done from PowerShell by loading a little C# as follows:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public static class Util
  {
      [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      public static extern int IsWow64GuestMachineSupported(ushort WowGuestMachineSupported, out bool machineIsSupported);
}
"@

$i386Supported = $false
[Util]::IsWow64GuestMachineSupported(0x014c,[ref] $i386Supported)

if ($i386Supported)
{
    Write-Output "i386 Supported";
}
```

This requires Windows 10 v1709 or Windows Server 2016 or later. If you have a customer with an older version of windows, I'd recommend giving them an upgrade.